# ¿Como cargar imagenes desde la galería en varios Image View?

Tags: android, image-view, gallery

**Descripción**

En mi app hay tres **Image Views** clickeables a las cuales me gustaría cargarle fotos de la galería, según que Image View se haya clickeado.

**Problema**

El problema es que con el código tipico que encontramos por internet para hacer esto, no puedo obtener la imágen para asignarselo al Image View que se haya clickeado.

**Adjunto el "código típico" con el que estoy trabajando**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/");
startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Selecciona algo"),10);
```

El problema está en **onActivityResult**, ya que la forma de obtención de la imágen, no me permite (hasta donde yo se) distribuir la imágen obtenida de la galería a cualquiera de los Image Views que se hayan clickeado.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable 
Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri path = data.getData();
        img_foto1.setImageURI(path);
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver, tengo la imágen capturada en la variable **"path"** pero no tengo forma de cambiar a que Image View se le va a asignar esa foto.

**Aclaración**

Además de que no encuentro forma de enviar la imágen capturada, al image view correspondiente, el código fue probado y no me funcionó (la imagen no aparecía en el image view).

**Adjunto la foto de las vistas de mi actividad**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Gracias por leer!**

**Edit**

Quiero aclarar que lo único que necesito es una forma dinámica para que el OnActivityResult sepa que image view se seleccionó para asi cargarle la imágen a dicho image view seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

podrias intentar manejar el cambio de tu `ImageView` utilizando un objeto `Bitmap`, asi llenas el mismo con el path obtenido de la imagen de tu galeria, lo haces de la siguiente forma:

**Declaras el Bitmap y un entero que servira para saber donde colocar tu imagen seleccionada**:

```
private Bitmap imagePicked;
private int numberImageSelected = 0;
```

**Luego, para realizar tu accion de selecionar imagen de galeria con Intent, la ejecutas de esta forma (teniendo en cuenta de donde haces click para saber a que imageView setear la imagen)**:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numberImageSelected = 1;
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 10);
        }
    });

    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numberImageSelected = 2;
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 10);
        }
    });

    imageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numberImageSelected = 3;
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 10);
        }
    });
```

Alli mismo estoy manejando el valor de "`numberImageSelected`" para saber desde donde estoy clickeando para setear la imagen.

**Ahora en el onActivityResult**:

```
if (requestCode==10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        try {
            imagePicked = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SetImage(imagePicked, numberImageSelected);
   }
```

Lo he trabajado de esta forma y me funciona bien. Se crea el `Bitmap`, se hace la peticion para seleccionar la imagen de la galeria (basicamente es lo mismo que tu estas haciendo pero en una sola linea, asi que puedes dejarlo como lo tienes si te parece mas comodo), y luego validas que el `requestCode` y el `resultCode` sean exitosos y que el campo "`data`" no venga nulo, se almacena el valor de la data en "`imageUri`" y luego con el `imagePicked` (`Bitmap`) almacenamos la imagen en si usando `getBitmap`, pasando como parametros `getContentResolver` para acceder a los datos del proveedor de contenido como contexto, y luego el `uri` o ruta de la imagen seleccionada.

Por ultimo creando una funcion sencilla y pasando como parametros el `Bitmap` y el `numberImageSelected` manejas el seteo de la imagen segun corresponda con un switch:

```
private void SetImage(Bitmap imageSelected, int ImageNumberSelected){
    switch (ImageNumberSelected){
        case 1:
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);
            numberImageSelected = 0;
            break;

        case 2:
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);
            numberImageSelected = 0;
            break;

        case 3:
            imageView3.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);
            numberImageSelected = 0;
            break;

            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "NO SE PUDO COLOCAR LA IMAGEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                numberImageSelected = 0;
                break;
    }
}
```

Asi en todo momento sabes de donde estas haciendo el clic y a donde debes setear la imagen segun eso, quizas exista otra forma de hacerlo pero esta es una forma sencilla.

Espero te sea util, aca puedes leer mas acerca de [proveedores de contenido](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics?hl=es).

Comment: Hola David. Muchas gracias por responder! El problema sigue siendo el mismo. Como  le indico al on activity result que Image View fue presionado? Supongamos que se seleccionó la image view 1 y la 2. Como puedo reemplazar la última línea de código que me escribiste (img_foto1.setImageBitmap...) por un código más dinámico que permita saber a que ImageView cargarle la foto?

Comment: Tomas he actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Hola David y gracias nuevamente. Tu código NO funcionó. Si bien lograste poder llevar la imágen a su Image View correspondiente, la imágen NO carga. En resumen: Clickeo una Image View, se abre la galería, toco una foto, le doy a ok y desaparece la image view con forma de foto (la cual adjunté en la pregunta) y solo queda el constraint layout. Esto pasa con las 3 image views. Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Bien, el codigo que actualice lo probe antes de subirlo y me funciona perfectamente, seteo las imagenes en el ImageView donde hago click, ahora dices que se desaparece el imageView con forma de foto, pregunto, quieres setear la Imagen en el Constraint layout y que quede el imageView con forma de foto sobre ella o setear la imagen en el imageView??? porque en este codigo que actualice hace exactamente eso y como te dije, funciona por que lo probe antes de subirlo, setea la imagen en el "ImageView" correspondiente.

Comment: El constraint layout está para contener a la image view y por motivos de estética. La Image View contiene un icono de camara por estética y además cumple la función de almacenar la imágen de la galería. Por ende, lo que quiero es que al presionar la image view, se abra la galería y al seleccionar una foto, esta se ponga en la image view que seguirá estando dentro del constraint layout. No se por que no me funcionó el código!!